# Is this the correct way to use Prototypes or is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a project and I have limited understanding of JavaScript and I've used Prototypes (one to try learn them, and two because it seemed like the great idea at the time).

I have a JS file that is just full of Prototypes and calls them like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dash = new Dash();
});

var Dash = function() {
    var _ = this;

    _.defaults = {
        pages: {},
        page_name: {},
        page_order: []
    };

    _.init();
};

Dash.prototype.init = function() {
    var _ = this;

    _.getPages();
    _.onClickNewPage();
    _.onClickEditPage();
};

Dash.prototype.getPages = function() {
    var _ = this;

    // calls some ajax
};
```

Pretty much all the Prototype methods just modify the page depending on what the user wants to see.

Is this the correct way to use Prototypes? If not is there a better way? What could I improve on and what are the memory implications of calling `var _ = this;` in each method to access other methods?

Apologies if this is an obvious question but all I'm finding on Google is Cat vs. Dog examples and they're not very useful.

I really want to make this code as efficient as possible whilst using best practises.

Also note: I'm not inheriting anything, just accessing different methods a lot.

Comment: How come this got down voted already? I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Do you have multiple dashes? If no, then making a class with prototypes is probably overengineered.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Bergi - is there anything that you'd change? I really don't want to realise rubbish code.

Comment: I'm not sure what multiple dashes are @Bergi so I'd presume not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pretty much all the Prototype methods just modify the page depending on what the user wants to see.

That's about the purpose of the code, which has nothing to do with prototypes or not.

> I'm not inheriting anything, just accessing different methods a lot. Is this the correct way to use Prototypes?

No. If you neither have inheritance nor multiple instances (and you create only one `new Dash` in your page), then using a class constructor with prototype methods is overcomplicated. There's no need for this.

> If not is there a better way?

Just use some kind of module pattern where you put all those functions as declarations in a common scope, or on an object literal if you want to focus on OOP and extensibility.

If you want to make the module reusable, wrap it in a function that returns the object.

> What are the memory implications of calling `var _ = this;` in each method to access other methods?

Local variables do not have any memory implications, but your `_` has a readability issue. Just go with the standard `this.` way of calling methods.